# Change Google Chrome's default incognito page without using external extensions

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, private-browsing

On my computer, Google Chrome opens in incognito automatically (I forced this using Group policy). This is mainly because I hate targeted ads (when I browse something on amazon, all ads suddenly show that product).

Now, what I hate about this setup is the basic "You have gone Incognito" page whenever I open my browser or a new tab page. Thus, I would like to change this to google.com or even a completely blank page is fine. I do not want to use external extensions to do this.

So, my questions are, **Where does Google Chrome store its incognito page?** and **Is this default behavior changeable, or should I replace the default incognito page with a blank one?**

I run Google Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: One quick google search and this gem popped up: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/646824/setting-a-homepage-in-incognito-mode-chrome/ The answer from @RetiredTeacher6s works, I just tested it. And you probably also noticed the fact that you do not need to edit any group policies for incognito to start.

Comment: You may load a .HTML file in incognito mode as a default page.